# SPI to USB and Terminal

Tags: spi

I would like to debug my microcntroller's program via SPI connected to PC.
(Usually UART is used for debug, but I would like to debug with higher frequencies such as SPI).

1. Can any one recomand me on PC terminal which is capable of recieving SPI comunication.
2. Also recomendation on SPI to USB adapter (connected to my PC).

Comment: You can do SPI with many of the FTDI cables that are available - this would be a simple and inexpensive solution.

Comment: When you write "PC Terminal" are you asking about software to display data received from some kind of SPI interface? By terminal you don't mean "Terminal emulator" do you?

Comment: Yes! I mean some SPI interface software to log received data. Can you recommand on one?

Comment: What is the SPI to USB you are using?

Comment: Sorry..More questions ..What  are you trying to debug with SPI? Has it been setup / initialized ?. Has the device had the wait state timing registers set to something the spi usb interface can use?..

Comment: I just trying to send data from micro controller to PC.
 i can use several SPI to USb adapter (link for an example one), but i am looking for PC software to receive the data. http://www.ebay.com/itm/ALL-IN-1-USB-to-SPI-I2C-IIC-UART-TTL-ISP-serial-Adapter-/201025056063?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item2ece06ed3f

Answer (score 1):

spi isn't the best way to debug stuff,because you can't hook it to a pc,and you need to convert it to something else, and if you want to debug something you don't rreally want more layer of "possible problems".

IMHO you should use something more standard like jtag debug or a logic analyzer but if you really want to use the spi you can use a [bus pirate](http://dangerousprototypes.com/docs/Bus_Pirate) or you can use an embedded system like the Raspberry of the beaglebone, in this way you can have access directly to the SPI via the GPIOs.

Comment: No, I'll explain.
Just as with UART, SPI enables me to send data with higher bit rate. there are several SPI to USB adapter (just like UART to USB), what i need is  Termina which knows to handle SPI recieved data. any one knows?

Answer (score -1):

If your using SPI it will appear as a standard com port on the PC. Then any standard Terminal program on a PC that can log  will be suitable. The SPI to USB lead handles the conversion.

On older windows PC I recormend Hyper Terminal because it's free.

Real Term I have used and works.

PuTTY was the last one I used and worked OK

**EDIT**
The device I was using was similar to a www.minicircuits.com/pdfs/RS232USB-SPI-N.pdf (This is not the device I used, I can't remeber back that far.)

This is described as a Bi-Directional Converter: RS232<-->SPI or USB<-->SPI.
It made it easy to send and recieve from the test station to PWB during production tests and for diagnostics when fault finding.

Search for "spi to usb" gives lots of chips and devices ..

Comment: Just a note. Speed will be determined by the device connected to and the SPI to USB Lead.

Comment: Thanks for your replay, But not every terminal support SPI communication. Hyperterminal for example does not, and Real Term did not work for me either.

Comment: Can you give an example of the type of SPI -> USB device whose output cannot be read by either a terminal program or by the software that comes with the device?

Comment: I have looked further into this... Do you have the correct drivers installed?